# Norm of Legendre Polynomials $P_m(x)$

Tags: integration, legendre-polynomials

While studying to prove the norm of Legendre polynomials $P_m(x)$ is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{2m+1}}$, I faced $\int_{-1}^{1} [D^m (x^2-1)^m]^2 dx = (2m)! \int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^m dx.$ $D^m$ stands for derivative of $m$-th degree. It seems to me I shoud use integration by parts of LHS $m$ times to arrive RHS. Please show me what is the detailed steps to do integration by parts of this case. I am confused by the existence of $D^m$ in this case. I am puzzled how to handle $D^m.$  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inductively integrate by parts
\begin{align*}\require{cancel}
&\int_{-1}^1 [D^{m-k}(x^2-1)^m][D^{m+k}(x^2-1)^m]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\cancel{\bigg[[D^{m-k-1}(x^2-1)^m][D^{m+k}(x^2-1)^m]\bigg]_{-1}^1}\\
&\quad-\int_{-1}^1 [D^{m-k-1}(x^2-1)^m][D^{m+k+1}(x^2-1)^m]\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
where $u=[D^{m+k}(x^2-1)^m]$, $\mathrm{d}v=[D^{m-k}(x^2-1)^m]\,\mathrm{d}x$ so $\mathrm{d}u=[D^{m+k+1}(x^2-1)^m]\,\mathrm{d}x$, $v=D^{m-k-1}(x^2-1)^m$ and $v=0$ at $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: You don't want negative powers of $D$ because that means doing integrals.  You go from $k=0$ to $k=m-1$ inductively to get $\int_{-1}^1[D^{2m}(x^2-1)^m](-1)^m(x^2-1)^m\,\mathrm{d}x$ and the $(2m)!$ comes from the first bracket (differentiating $(x^2-1)^{m}$ $2m$ times).

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. After integrating by parts $ m $ times, $ \int_{-1}^{1} [ D^m (x^2-1)^m]^2 dx =(-1)^m \int_{-1}^{1} [D^{-k} (x^2-1)^m][D^{2m+k} (x^2-1)^m] dx $. Then, does this mean $ (-1)^m \int_{-1}^{1} D^{2m} (x^2-1)^{2m} dx $? Also, how $ (2m)! \int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^m dx $ is obtained. Sorry for beginner's question, but I am yet to reach my goal.   P.S. I have difficulty in using Mathjax.  I am studying.  Please bear with me.

Comment: I understand your additional explanation.  $ (-1)^m \int_{-1}^{1} [D^{-k} (x^2-1)^m] [ D^{2m+k} (x^2-1)^m ] dx = \int_{-1}^{1} [D^{2m}(x^2-1)^m] (-1)^m  (x^2-1)^m dx = (2m)!  \int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^m dx $   I finally obtained my desired result.  Thank you again for your excellent explanation.